Definitive "How did you become a quant?" community wiki
A variation of the dreaded "How do I become a quant?" gets posted pretty regularly. (A related one is "How do I come-up with trading strategies?", which I find even worse.) I propose to have a canonical page that everyone can point to, much like the "Where can I find free data online?" wiki.
Users can post their own experiences and then we'll have a collection of stories that will act as the answer. This exercise will hopefully show that there is tremendous variation in both job functions and career paths.

@mods Any objections to this idea?

No, not at all, I'd say go for it!

Given that there have not been any objections, this question has now been posted.
This must be a community wiki because no one should earn rep points for this. Future career questions can be redirected to this definitive list of anecdotes, though there will be some career questions that will presumably be closed outright.
